# How do I copy a few columns to another file in Python?

Tags: python, loops, awk

I couldn't find a similar question here or an existing solution.

I have a written in Python code that shows me which columns from file1 should be rejected. I would like to write a short script which prints the valid columns + the last column to a file2.

```
File1 (input):
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,...,col(n-1),coln

Python code chooses some of them, for example col3, col5, col6, col20

File2 (output):
col3,col5,col6,col20,coln
```

I was thinking about creating a loop with awk, but I am not sure how to add new columns to only one file with each iteration:

```
cmd1='''awk -F "," '{print $indices[f]}' data.csv > temp[i].csv'''
cmd2='''awk -F "," {'{print $0}' temp[i].csv '{print $[i+1]}'} data.csv} > temp[i+1].csv'''

print("Feature ranking:")

for f in range(X.shape[1]):
    if(importances[indices[f]]>0.01):
         print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, indices[f], importances[indices[f]]))
    while(importances[indices[f]]>0.01):
        os.system(cmd1)
        os.system(cmd2)
```

Comment: "How do I use awk in a loop" is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have some problem and you think calling awk in a loop is the solution so you're asking how to implement that but **maybe** (probably!) calling awk in a loop isn't the best solution to your problem. If you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you. Since you've already started writing a python script, why do you want an awk script now? Are you thinking about calling awk from python or vice-versa?

Comment: Why do you want to use `python` then `awk` rather than only one of these?

Comment: If for some reason you wish Python to select columns, then awk to process File1 with selected columns (??), why don't you just create the AWK script on the fly using Python ?  Either modify a sample template awk script or create it totally from scratch.

Comment: Could you recommend me a good method in Python to do so? I often use awk when I want to rewrite some columns from one file to another, but probably there is a better solution.

Comment: This is very much a python question so you should consider adding a python tag to it. I have to believe the right answer won't involve calling awk from python as what you describe would be trivial in awk alone so hopefully it's not difficult directly in python either!